# how to write Hello world servlet Program

Tags: java, servlets

This is my Helloworld class

```
 package java4s;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class Helloworlsclass
     */
    @WebServlet("/Helloworlsclass")
    public class Helloworlsclass extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public Helloworlsclass() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
                printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
```

this is web Xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>


              HelloWorld
          </servlet-name>
          <sevlet-class>

              /Helloworlsclass

          </sevlet-class>



          <servlet-mapping>
              HelloWorld

          </servlet-mapping>


          <url-pattern>


              /Helloworlsclass
          </url-pattern>
      </servlet>
    </web-app>
```

I am trying to Run using this Example But Browser doesn't Print any thing please tell me where am doing mistake how to Print hello world in in servlet Example

Comment: servlet-class value should be fully qualified class e.g. java4s.Helloworlsclass

Answer (score 1):

You aren't writing a complete valid HTML page, only a heading.

And as you're using the annotation, you don't need the web.xml stuff at all.

Comment: Please tell me how i write hello world i want write simple hello world Program using servlet please help .

Comment: Then please tell me how to write hello world Web application using servlet

Comment: And then maybe making a coffee for you ? There are **tones** of examples and tutorials. Have you tried with Google ? :)

Comment: yes I have Tried But when i run that Project then am not getting Out Put please help me

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/
   Error is coming  now please tell how to Fix

Comment: @DevRaj What URL are you using? You can try /Helloworlsclass after the webapp path or change the url-pattern to /HelloWorld